# Using class argument as function decorator in Python

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I have a Python class

```
class A:

    def __init__(self, auth):
        self.auth = auth
```

I want to use the `auth` variable as a function decorator but when I do something like below, it gives and error:

```
@self.auth.some_method()
def func(self):
    pass
```

the above does not work. Can someone please help with this. Thanks

Comment: `self` is just a parameter to the `__init__` method; it doesn't exist outside a method.

Comment: Is `func` supposed to be another method of `A`? The instance containing the decorator you want can't exist before you finish defining `A`, which is when the decorator would be applied.

Comment: Yes that makes sense. `func` is a method of class `A`. How can I use that decorator? any suggestions please?

Comment: You can't. You can't decorate a method after the class has already been defined. If the purpose of the method is to simply modify the return value, you can change `def func(self): return something` to `def func(self): return self.auth.something_or_other(something)`, apply a function saved as an instance attribute to the "raw" return value before actually returning it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest doing something like this:

```py
class A:
    def __base_func(self):
        pass

    def __init__(self, auth):
        self.auth = auth
        self.func = auth.some_method(self.__base_func)
```

Comment: `func` is not an instance method then; it's just a `function`-valued instance attribute.

Comment: I didn't know there was a difference... would it be possible to use `setattr()` inside the init method?

Comment: No; a method is a *class* attribute, and the descriptor protocol is what makes `A().foo` return a `method` object based on the function (with `self` "prebound" to `A()`,  whereas `A.foo` returns the `function` itself).